# Is it possible to specify example executables for a library as optional in a cabal package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I.e. this isn't legal:

```
if someFlag {
  executable someExec {
  }
}
```

Is there some way to do this anyway? If not, is it good practice to supply examples as a separate cabal package instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[reactive-banana-wx](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/reactive-banana-wx.cabal) does exactly this.

First, define a flag:

```
flag buildExamples
    description: Build example executables
    default: False
```

Then, for each executable, you can set `buildable : false` to not build it:

```
Executable Arithmetic
    if flag(buildExamples)
        build-depends: reactive-banana, wx, wxcore, base
    else
        buildable: False
    hs-source-dirs: src
    main-is: Arithmetic.hs
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
executable someExec
  if (someFlag)
    buildable: True
  else
    buildable: False
```